# What variety of sweet potato is best for lower grow temperatures?

Tags: variety-selection, sweet-potato

I'm looking for sweet potato variety most suitable for temperate climate zone (central Europe). Especially, I need some variety that tolerates lower night temperatures (usually between 10 and 15 °C).

I had some success with purple and white variety: https://youtu.be/2YSddfu0wpQ

However, any orange flesh variety I tried always fails. I tried with beauregard and other similar (I don't know what variety is it, bought from market and got slips from it).

Can you recommend any orange flesh variety with lowest thermal requirements? And where to buy (ideally with ability to ship to Europe - PL). I've heard about Canadian Radiance - new variety designed for colder climate zones, but it'd curtently not possibile to buy slips or tuber, copyright law restricts it to be sell only to Canadian growers